How to turn off ssl cert verification in Polars while reading parquet from s3
I am trying to read parquet from a self hosted instance of minio which has a self signed cert.
I am using the following code
import polars as pl
storage_options = {
"aws_access_key_id": "s3-key",
"aws_secret_access_key": "s3secretkey",
"endpoint_url": "https://<s3instance>.com",
}
file_path = 's3://<bucketname>/data.parquet'
pl.read_parquet(file_path, storage_options=storage_options)

On executing this i get the bellow error
polars.exceptions.ComputeError: Generic S3 error: Error after 2 retries in 1.91494864s, max_retries:2, retry_timeout:10s, source:error sending request for url (https://<s3instance>/<bucketname>/data.parquet): error trying to connect: invalid peer certificate: UnknownIssuer

I understand this is coming because of the self signed certificate and am trying to get Polars not to verify this cert.
i have tried
 storage_options = {
"aws_access_key_id": "s3-key",
"aws_secret_access_key": "s3secretkey",
"endpoint_url": "https://<s3instance>.com",
"client_kwargs": {"verify": "False"}
}

and
 storage_options = {
"aws_access_key_id": "s3-key",
"aws_secret_access_key": "s3secretkey",
"endpoint_url": "https://<s3instance>.com",
"verify": "False"
}

but this does not help.
How can i turn of cert verification in Polar while reading parquet ?
